# Moving a div further down a page

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm using this plugin on a wordpress theme http://www.ihomefinder.com/products/optima-express/

When the search results are shown there is a map at the top of the listings. Is there any way to move it to the bottom of the listings but above the next/previous buttons?

http://www.denverrealestate.house/castle-pines/

Comment: Hi there, Have you wrote the template yourself?

Comment: no, the site is built around a wordpress theme and the listings i think are pulled in using the ihomefinder plugin

Answer (score 0):

You should just check the suggestion provided here:  [Ihomefinder Support - Theme Templates](http://support.ihomefinder.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/92/22/theme-templates)
As the map is displayed in one row above all the listings, I guess it should be possible - in case no other template for this page is provided - to add a new template based on the one currently used and just change the order of e.g. the php-includes. It's possible that you notice something like php_getMap() with php_getResultList() below (just as example) and could just change this to have the result list on top.

Comment: I can't find any template pages. There are lots of 'virtual pages' but can't find anything referring to 'map'

Comment: it looks to me like the ihomefinder idx plugin pulls the content in ready formatted. If anyone wants to have a look all the files are in here... http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/optima-express.latest-stable.zip

Comment: Guess you're right, just checked the files as well as the live result page and found various ajax-calls that, if called properly, would result in ready formatted snippets; sure it would be possible to add some js to be called after the page loaded and just cut the map from top and append it above the prev/next buttons, but I really wouldn't recommend that. As ihomef. states editability + support you should just ask them if it's possible to adjust it in a proper way.

Comment: I did and they said it wasn't an option :s trouble is the client really wants it.

Comment: Sorry for that. Should be possible for them to adjust it as they only attach the map to a container (with the id "ihf-map-canvas") which could be 1st as well as last row, though there might be some unknown issues when attaching at the bottom.